# Starred fixed-width messages break in the starboard

Tags: bug, chat, code-block, chat-stars, fixed-width

> [image]

FHRC#1 indicates a backquote in a chat message using fixed-width formatting, which is (correctly) output literally. FHRC#2 shows that the same backquote is misinterpreted by the sidebar starboard as a formatting character, wrecking the intended look and feel even more.

If you can't quite see it, compare the message rendering:

```js
var f = function() {
  var s = $(this).val();
  var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
  var lastBacktick = s.indexOf("`", cursorPosition);
  // remainder of code elided due to being irrelevant
```

with the sidebar rendering:

> var f = function() { var s = $(this).val(); var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart; var lastBacktick = s.indexOf("`", cursor...`

Notice the backquote being taken as a formatting delimiter, when it really shouldn't be.